# How do I record a Repository from one Agency but different sections?

Tags: sources, proof, queensland, research-guides

I have obtained:

1. Birth and Death Certificates from Queensland Birth, death and marriage certificates, https://www.qld.gov.au/law/births-deaths-marriages-and-divorces/birth-death-and-marriage-certificates and
2. Birth, Marriage and Death Certificates & Images from the Family history research service, https://www.familyhistory.bdm.qld.gov.au/.

Both are areas within Queensland Births, deaths, marriages and divorces, https://www.qld.gov.au/law/births-deaths-marriages-and-divorces.

Do these come from one Repository or from two?

Would I record the Repository as:

Queensland Births, deaths, marriages and divorces and identify the section within the Repository

or would I record the applicable section as the Repository

Queensland Births, deaths and marriages and

Queensland Family history research service.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is the place where the record is located – in this case it appears to be Brisbane Registry. It doesn't matter whether you ordered the certificate online, by mail, went to the repository in person, etc.

I would be careful relying too much on linking to individual pages on a government website as these change very frequently and will likely become obsolete before long.

When documenting any source, if someone can find their way back to that source, you have done your job. It is not usually necessary to record every step you took to get to that source.

Comment: I'd agree with the answer above. The Repository is where the record comes from. The different URLs appear to be just different means of accessing the same certificates. And as Harry V says, such URLs and web page titles alter all the time. I couldn't immediately see if there's any reason to use one URL or the other. Please comment if I'm missing anything.